# Is "When it could be [past participle]" a valid question?

Tags: questions, past-participles

I wonder if someone tell me is "When it could be [past participle]" a valid question?

> E.g "When this computer could be restarted".

I've searched google and didn't find a similar example.

Comment: Almost, but "could" is in the wrong place, it should be "When could it...?"

Comment: **When could this computer be restarted?** is a question. If you wanted to use your example in a statement, you could say something like: **We are trying to establish when this computer could be restarted.**